# Fill Color between Margin and Input Element Border

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I have created a layout for a html form. [HTML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zivJy.png)

Now when error occurs i want to fill color between the rounded part that i have shown. Is it possible? If not then is there any other way to do so using **JavaScript**??
Any kind of help is appreciated.!
Thank You

```
</div>
        <form class="form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="textbox" /> 
            <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Number'  class='textbox' />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="textbox" /> 
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="textbox" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"  class="textbox" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Register" class="button" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add extra elements to your form. Wrap the inputs in a div and add an arrow. Like this:

```
<div>
    <form class="form">
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="textbox" /> 
        </div>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Employee Number'  class='textbox' />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="textbox" /> 
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="textbox" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"  class="textbox" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Register" class="button" />
    </form>
</div>
```

.triangle should be positioned absolute and .wrapper relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/d492173y/2/

Comment: Well..That's not what I actually wanted. I wanted a triangle kind of thing at the corners. Anyways thanks for the answer, I can go with it at this time. :)